# Latex - Image displaying text instead of image

Tags: latex, overleaf

Here is my code:

```latex
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image_135.png}
\end{center}
```

Here is what shows up:

[image: text displayed instead of image]

I'm not sure if it is important, but I use Overleaf as an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the compile mode from fast to normal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the referenced file does not exist (or is not located in the expected path).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).